# Is it possible to add class template specialization and effect previous usages of this class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have some header file with declared template class and template function:

**print.h:**

```cpp
template<typename T> struct Printer {
  static void print();
};

template<typename T> void print();
```

In the implementation file, I have some base implementation of `Printer`, some specializations of it, and implementation of the function `print` that calls `Printer<T>::print`.

**print.cpp**

```cpp
template<typename T> void Printer<T>::print() {
  cout << "base";
}

template<> struct Printer<int> {
  static void print() {
    cout << "int";
  }
};

template<> struct Printer<bool> {
  static void print() {
    cout << "bool";
  }
};

template<typename T> void print() {
  return Printer<T>::print();
}
```

In another file, I add one more specialization of `Printer` and a call of function `print` after it.

**another.cpp**

```cpp
template<> struct Printer<char> {
  static void print() {
    cout << "char";
  }
};

void printChar() {
  print<char>();
}
```

Which `Printer<T>::print` does `printChar` call? Base or specialization `Printer<char>`? Can I change the behavior of `printChar` in this way?

(print.cpp is compiled first)

---

I compiled this code in a single file in the same order and called `printChar`. The output is 'char'. But I am not sure that it will work in different files as I described. Because for me it looks like it opens the ability to extend existing code by something like a cheating injection. But maybe it is OK to practice (Swift is based on a similar kind of extensions). If it works, Is it ok to practice it?

Comment: What is `value`? A template parameter that we don't see?

Comment: You can't implement function templates in separate `cpp` files.

Comment: @Evg If they are only used in that TU, it should be ok?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yes. Here we have a mixture of templates and specializations.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am implementing a bridge from OCaml to C++ and it is sampled from my real code. value - isn't the template parameter, it is some third party type.

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko Ok, so for demo purposes, you could just write `int` there? It's easier to read if one understands what we're dealing with.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are right. I added some executable code in the note. I will edit my example with Printer a bit later.

Comment: As long as you follow the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) I think you should be fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo done. I edited my question to better form.

Comment: You don't have more than one full template specialization for any of the types? If so, I think you're good - but this isn't my strongest area so I'll let someone else answer. My answer would just be copy paste from the ODR-link :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which *previous usages* you're referring to. I see only one usage of `print<char>`, after the specialization of `print<char>`.

Templates work kind of like `#define`, they stamp out definitions on-demand as needed. So the right template specialization definition had better be available at the time the code needs to be stamped out, which by the way takes place independently per TU. And these definitions must be identical across TU's.

See [[temp.expl.spec]/pp.6-7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.expl.spec#6):

> <sup>6</sup> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

> <sup>7</sup> The placement of explicit specialization declarations ... can affect whether a program is well-formed according to the relative positioning of the explicit specialization declarations and their points of instantiation in the translation unit as specified above and below. When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation.

So as long as `print<char>` is instantiated *after* the specialization of `print<char>` *in every translation unit* where it is used (including implicit instantiations), the program is fine. The `printChar()` case is OK. But if `print<char>` happens to be instantiated in any other TU, the program would become ill-formed NDR.

For this reason all specializations are usually bundled (included) in the same **header** file that declares the primary template. It might increase compile times but can save a lot of headache during program development and maintenance later on.

Comment: I have specialization of `Printer<char>` after `template<typename T> void print()` that calls `Printer<T>::print()`. Thats why I worry that  the `print<char>()` call from `void printChar()` calls `print<T>` but `print<T>` know nothing about `Printer<char>` specialization because it declared after `print<T>`. So, base generic implementation possibly called instead of `Printer<char>` specialization.

Comment: I moved `Printer<char>` definition to the end of the file (the single file where all sources from the question are). So, when `Printer<char>` declared after `int main() { printChar(); }` the output still is 'char'. But as I understand from your answer it should be 'base'.

Comment: So for me, it looks like the following scenario is correct. I have some program that has no `Printer<char>` specialization and print 'base' everywhere where printChar() is called. I added a new file to the end of the compilation list with `Printer<char>` specialization and the program started to print 'char' instead 'base' where `printChar()` is called. I think so, based on my investigation with a single file. As I know C++ doesn't support open recursion (everything should be declared before use). But in this case, it works differently.